# Is it possible to integrate IBM MQ with Quarkus while also enabling transaction support?

Tags: transactions, jms, ibm-mq, quarkus

IBM MQ does not support Transactions with AMQP. Is there a way to connect Quarkus with IBM MQ so that I can use TX without having to do all the heavy lifting myself?

For some reason IBM MQ supports AMQP but without support for transactions, see https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.0?topic=mq-amqp-clients-communicating-over. So using QPid or any other AMQP-Framework that integrates nicely with Quarkus is not an option.

Is there another extension that could be used with IBM MQ and that offers transactional support? AFAIK quarkus-artemis-jms is not suitable since IBM MQ uses a proprietary wire-protocol.

This answer suggests to implement everything within the application: [Quarkus IBM MQ integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60259012/quarkus-ibm-mq-integration)
But that seems like a very bad idea, since TX-related code is hard to test and reliability is the main reason for my projetct to even use TX.

Is there any other reliable approach to integrate MQ with Quarkus AND have TX support?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether you want just want to run with Quarkus or want to run as a native executable with Quarkus / GraalVM.

If you are only making use of Quarkus then you can use the IBM MQ JMS client.  https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.ibm.mq/com.ibm.mq.allclient

The optimization in the IBM MQ JMS client is incompatible with the optimization that takes place when building a Quarkus / GraalVM native executable.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but the issue is with using the IBM JMS client. There is no binding between Quarkus and the IBM JMS client. Using the IBM client means implementing transactional behaviour on our own within the application instead of just using @Transactional. There is no Quarkus extension that works with the IBM client. quarkus-artemis-jms won't work with IBM MQ and quarkus-qpid-jms relies on AMQP for which IBM MQ does not support transactions. 
Optimizing for native execution is not relevant for our use case.